# Julia dataeye not working

Tags: julia

I was following allow with the YouTube Video on ["Data Analysis in Julia with Data Frames (John Myles White)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRClA5YLiIc)

I got to the Convenience constructors section, dataeye, etc...  however, I get the following in Julia 0.3.3:

```
julia> dm = dataeye(2)  
ERROR: dataeye not defined
```

Where is the `dataeye()` function located/defined?

BTW: where is the RDatasets, that is used in the video?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to take what you posted and distill it into something a bit more concentrated. Imagine you're writing an e-mail to your coworker. It is very hard for us to read paragraphs and paragraphs and figure out what you want. Give a couple of sentences of background, explain what you need to, then state your question explicitly. That way, it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: RDataSets is here https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/RDatasets.jl

Answer (score 6):

I think dataeye used to be in DataArrays (and hence DataFrames), it doesn't seem to be used anymore and I can't find it on github for either of these projects. It looks like it was a shorthand/is not written:

```
@data eye(2)

julia> @data eye(4)
4x4 DataArray{Float64,2}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

*All I could find was [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-stats/7Y2m_9uzQJY) saying they're not very useful (presumably they were then removed)...*

Comment: couldn't quite find the commit, but as you can see it was deprecated https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataArrays.jl/commit/11d190fa61875149b4decb3f81cc32da0961810e#diff-c5cf4149fb7b9543a3f4cd7d9746163eL120